# How to write here? try: except for ZeroDivisionError: print "You cannot divide by zero!"

Tags: python, calculator

Help, how to avoid division error?

```
what = input ("+\n-\n/\n*\nЧто делаем?:")
a = float(input("\nВведите первое число:"))
b= float(input("Введите второе число:"))

if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print("\nРезультат:" + str(c))

elif what == "/":
    c = a / b
    print("\nРезультат:" + str(c))


elif what == "*":
    c = a * b
    print("\nРезультат:" + str(c))

elif what == "-":
    c = a - b
    print("\nРезультат:" + str(c))

else:
    print ("\nНеизвестный символ.")
input()
```

Where to insert?
try:
except ZeroDivisionError: print "Can't divide by zero!"

Comment: Where there is division. And better than that, just check whether ```b != 0``` instead of adding the "try ... except ..."

Comment: In :    elif what =='/': if(b!=0): c= a/b

Comment: You use try block to **test** a portion of the code for eventual exceptions, and you use **except** for managing whatever exception could occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Do it this way

```
what = input ("+\n-\n/\n*\nЧто делаем?:")
a = float(input("\nВведите первое число:"))
b= float(input("Введите второе число:"))

if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print("\nРезультат:" + str(c))

elif what == "/":
    try:
        c = a / b
        print("\nРезультат:" + str(c))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Can't divide by zero!")

elif what == "*":
    c = a * b
    print("\nРезультат:" + str(c))

elif what == "-":
    c = a - b
    print("\nРезультат:" + str(c))

else:
    print ("\nНеизвестный символ.")
input()
```